# Receive only 'text' from Telegram bot when a user uploads an image

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bots, telegram

I set up an AWS Lambda webhook to a Telegram bot. Regular messages are passed to event properly, but when a user uploads an image only 'text is passed to event. What could be the problem?

[Screenshot of the received data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOXGP.png)

```
def hello(event, context):
try:
    data = json.loads(event["body"])
    originalBody = str(data)
    message = str(data["message"]["text"])
    chat_id = data["message"]["chat"]["id"]
    first_name = data["message"]["chat"]["first_name"]
    print(data)

    response = "Please /start, {}".format(first_name)

    if "start" in message:
        response = "Hello {}".format(first_name)

    #data = {"text": response.encode("utf8"), "chat_id": chat_id}
    data = {"text": "heyyyy!", "chat_id": chat_id}
    url = BASE_URL + "/sendMessage"
    requests.post(url, data)
    requests.post(url, originalBody)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

return {"statusCode": 200}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? As an aside, using `except Exception` like that is a bad idea, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Comment: I solved the problem. Thanks for the link about exceptions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just accessed variables the wrong way. "text" is just the name of the key, it was not found in the event with photo.